# Incorporating stills into a video

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am incorporating still into a video using the VSE. When I put an image into the video and preview it the images is way deformed to fit into the output of the video settings. Is there a way to ask Blender to automatically fit the image into the video to match the output of say 1080 or 720? The stills I am using are of various sizes.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an addon for blender available at https://github.com/mutantbob/blender-letterbox which can be used to quickly add and configure the necessary Effect Strip.

After you have installed this addon from the .py file ([instructions](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/scripting/python/add_ons.html)) you can either use the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> menu to invoke the letterbox operator, or find it in the Strip menu of the VSE panel.

Answer (score 0):

**Transform Effect Strip**

In the Blender VSE use the Transform Effect Strip.
The effect strip will be conceptually linked to the original as a pair.
It change change size and location of the image.

[image]

If the images are all the same size you can duplicate [Shift D] the pair you created above, drag to new position, and then change the source image, with the button [Change Data Files] indicated.

[image]

Comment: Atomic, can you show step by step screen captures. I got to the part of adding transform strip, but now I do not understand how to modify the transform to do what I need it to.